# PowerGREP-lite like regular expression tool

Tags: windows, text-search, regex

I frequently need to do a lot of "search and replace" within a single file. I have a text file where I store my regex searches, but as the number of items increases it becomes tedious to copy-paste and apply each one of them.

Sublime Text has a package called `Reg​Replace` but I couldn't figure out how it works (my bad). PowerGREP is powerful, but has a horrible interface and user experience; and expensive.

What other choice do I to quickly apply my stored regex searches?

(I am on Windows 7 64 bit. I am looking for freeware, but I am willing to pay for a good software.)

Comment: See the various answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856009/win-batch-regexp-search-and-replace) for ideas. (Posting as a comment because I don't have any experience with any of them and can't vouch for any of them.)